# How to reuse a checkpointed DF in pyspark if a spark-submit pyspark sql batch job fails?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I checkpointed a dataframe in a hdfs path using the below command after few transformations. All my cluster nodes have access to this hdfs path.

spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(hdfs path)

df5 = df4.checkpoint()

I am able to use this checkpointed dataframe during the rest of the job without issues, if the job goes smoothly. I am using Apache airflow for orchaestration.

I need clarification on below queries:

1. in case of a job failure post checkpointing and rerun of the spark-submit job, i am not sure how to resume the job from this checkpointed version. It seems the checkpointed df is not being used automatically and all the prior transformations are executed again.
2. how do you take care of the deletion of the checkpointed files after pyspark job completion. Do you run a separate bash script after spark job completion as part of your pipeline to achieve this?
3. can we customize somehow the name of the folder that the checkpointed dataframe will be saved at within the checkpointed directory? currently it saves in the path "{checkpoint dir}/{random number}/rdd-{random number}"